# Http request error using firebase functions/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

Ive been trying unsuccessfully to get an http request to the Genius API server running through my cloud functions node.js instance. I am currently stuck getting this 'Server Error' message and am not sure how else to move around this. I am new to http requests, so was wondering if there were any glaring mistakes im making in this request? Or possible ideas for how to get more useful information from the error console

My console log currently outputs:
(node:43068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Server error.

> ```
>  at /Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/xxx/functions/index.js:58:21
>  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
>  (node:43068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1))
> ```

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3035
var http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

    
app.get('/auth', (req, res) => {

    const accessToken ='xxx';
    const clientId = 'xxx';
    const clientSecret = 'xxx';

    const uri = `https://api.genius.com/oauth/authorize`;
      const options = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
                "code": "CODE_FROM_REDIRECT",
                "client_id": clientId,
                "client_secret": clientSecret,
                "redirect_uri": "YOUR_REDIRECT_URI",
                "response_type": "code",
                "grant_type": "authorization_code"
          }),
      };
      return fetch(uri, options).then((res) => {
          if (res.ok) {
              return res.json();
          } else if (res.status == 409) {
              throw new Error('IdP configuration already exists. Update it instead.');
          } else {
              throw new Error('Server error.');
          }
      });

  })
  

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `then` handler you are throwing exceptions that are not `catch`ed anywhere (at least not in the code you are showing us). Thus, you get an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`. And as this is all inside an express routehandler, you are not returning anything to your client calling this route (not even if the authenication call is successful)

```
app.get('/auth', (reqest, response) => {

    const accessToken ='xxx';
    const clientId = 'xxx';
    const clientSecret = 'xxx';

    const uri = `https://api.genius.com/oauth/authorize`;
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "code": "CODE_FROM_REDIRECT",
        "client_id": clientId,
        "client_secret": clientSecret,
        "redirect_uri": "YOUR_REDIRECT_URI",
        "response_type": "code",
        "grant_type": "authorization_code"
      }),
    };

    fetch(uri, options).then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
          return res.json();
        } else if (res.status == 409) {
          throw new Error('IdP configuration already exists. Update it instead.');
        } else {
          throw new Error('Server error.');
        }
      })
      .then(json => {
        response.send(json);  // will send status 200 and the json as body 
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        response.sendStatus(400);  //or whatever status code you want to return
      });

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Often you may need to do some tweaks to the data before it's passed to the consumer, for example:

```
fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.statusText)
      }
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(data => {
      return data.data
    })
    .catch((error: Error) => {
      throw error
    })
```